# Force text to display in two lines from css

Tags: html, css

I have a css problem, which seems very easy.
I have a text, as you can see below: "Big ideas. Lasting value."

[image]

When I am on mobile devices I need to display this text on two lines. I have tried a lot of possibilities, but none of them has worked for me.

This is the html code:

```
 <div class="home_firstrow" id="panel-one">
    <div>
        <h3> Big Ideas. Lasting Value.</h3>
        <div class="container"> 
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

I have tried to put for the h3 element the :

```
white-space: normal
```

I've tried to set the

```
 heigth
```

and

```
min-heigth
```

but none of these worked for me. Do you have any idea what can I try?
The problem is I need to resolve this from css. I need the text in two line only in mobile view.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the issue is `heigth`  and `min-heigth`?

Comment: Can you target `width` property instead of `height`?

Comment: Insert an actual line break in the content (I prefer to use `&#10;` to make it absolutely clear that this is an intended line break), and use `white-space: pre` (or `pre-line`, depending on whether you might need it to wrap in other places as well if there is not enough space.)

Comment: use css framework  like bootstrap ..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using popular css framework is better for your site ! However you can try like this in css .Control by `@media (max-width:..)`

```css
   h3 {
    width:100%;
    }
    h3 span {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    }
    /*in mobile view ,give full width each span */
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
     h3 span {
       width:100%;
       background:red;
     }
    }
```

```html
 <h3><span>Big Ideas.</span><span>Lasting Value.</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Just use media query when using this. Because it has a fixed `width`;

```css
h3{
    width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_firstrow" id="panel-one">
    <div>
        <h3> Big Ideas. Lasting Value.</h3>
        <div class="container"> 
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake in writing `heigth` spelling

its `height` not `heigth`

so write `height` instead of `heigth`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }`.